# Excel - import data from cell automatically when a new tab is created

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am working on a spreadsheet summarizing data from standard templates inserted in a joint Excel file as separate tabs.

Is it possible to automatically import data from a specified cell into a summary tab, when a new tab is created? Since the data I want to extract is in the same cell in each document, this would save me a lot of time and effort

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will create a list in sheet1 column A of Sheet Names, and every time cell `C1` on **any sheet** changes, it will place the value of that cell into sheet1 in column B, next to the corresponding sheet name in column A

It goes in the `ThisWorkbook` module through the VBA editor*. You can change the sheet name and ranges as needed.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("C1")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
        Dim iRow As Integer
        On Error GoTo Yikes:
TryAgain:
        iRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sh.Name, ws.Range("A1:A50"), 0)
        ws.Cells(iRow, 2) = Target.Value
        Exit Sub

Yikes:

        Dim rowcount As Integer
        rowcount = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim r As Range
        Set r = ws.Cells(rowcount + 1, 1)
        r = Sh.Name
        GoTo TryAgain:
    End If
End Sub
```

**To get to the VBA editor, you must go to the office button, excel options and in the popular tag, place a checkmark in the box next to `Show Developer tab in the Ribbon`. Then close that out, go to the developer tab and click the `Visual Basic` button on the far left. The editor will open up and you will need to double click the `ThisWorkbook` module on the left pane.*